# Git - Clean up commits after pull from main

Tags: git, github

I am currently working on a feature branch but in order to continue I need to pull some changes from main. That is no issue - I can do that.

However, I would like to clean up the history so that in my PR you can only see one commit. How can this be done after having pulled (and merged) from main?

So far my procedure was like this:

- Do my regular work on my feature branch
- If I ended up pushing x commits to my feature branch, I fixed up the commits. To do this I did a `git rebase -i HEAD~<x>` so e.g. `git rebase -i HEAD~2` if I have done two commits. In the resulting dialogue I marked the older commits as fixup and I reworded the last commit if necessary (to have one meaningful commit message)
- Then I pushed to my feature branch `git push -u origin +<my feature branch>`

This procedure worked quite well - until I needed to pull from main. If I do this approach, I only end up having one commit. But if on main e.g. a file has been added, I see that file as an added file on my branch too (in the PR). Is there a way to avoid that? I would like to have a PR as clean as possible - so only seeing my changes and only having one commit in the history.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you `rebase` again against the new `main` branch?

Answer (score 0):

This sound like you most probably don't want to actually `git pull` the changes from the main branch but rather do one of the following two things:

1. `git checkout main` then `git pull` and `git checkout feature1` again to do a `git rebase main` there
2. This is the "faster" way: simply fetch the remote via `git fetch origin` and then run `git rebase origin/main` inside your `feature1` branch